# Java with jython

Tags: java, jython-2.7

I am exporting a Java application with a Jython script using Eclipse to jar file.
The Jython script executes when I run the code in the Eclipse IDE but it doesn't execute when I run the jar file of the same code.

I am executing the jython script from a java function using

```
                   PythonInterpreter interp = new PythonInterpreter();
                   interp.execfile(".com\\sample\\Script.py");
```

and I am including the jython2.7 jar in build path as external jar and using same jar as interpreter in the PyDeV perspective.

Comment: Show us how do you execute that script.

Comment: It seems like you used a "not-universally" usable getter for your "path/to/jython-script"... But a little more information would raise your chance to get an adequate answer!

Comment: @M. Prokhorov                                                                             
I am executing the jython script from a java function using                        PythonInterpreter interp = new PythonInterpreter();
interp.execfile(".com\\sample\\Script.py");  and I am including the jython2.7 jar in build path as external jar and using same jar as interpreter in the PyDeV perspective.

Comment: @PrR3                                                                             
I am executing the jython script from a java function using                        PythonInterpreter interp = new PythonInterpreter();
interp.execfile(".com\\sample\\Script.py");                                           
and I am including the jython2.7 jar in build path as external jar and using same jar as interpreter in the PyDeV perspective.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a code fix like this:

```
InputStream stream = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(".com\\sample\\Script.py");
PythonInterpreter interp = new PythonInterpreter();
interp.execfile(stream);
```

I hope this solves your problem! 
If not, feel free to give us more detailed information to investigate on your issues. (Maybe redirect System.out and System.err to logfile...)